# Angular custom style to mat-dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to customize the default "mat-dialog" in Angular 5. 
What I want to achieve is having a toolbar in the upper part of the dialog, which should cover the whole width. 
However, the mat-dialog-container has a fixed padding of 24px which I could not override. I tried to style both the h1 and the mat-dialog-container.

```
@Component({
selector: 'error-dialog',
template: 
` <h1 mat-dialog-title> ERRORE </h1>             
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        {{data.error}}
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="onClick()">Ok</button> 
    </div>`,
styles: [
'h1 { background: #E60000; color: white; }',
// 'myDialogStyle .mat-dialog-container { padding: 1px !important;}'
]})

export class ErrorDialog {
constructor(
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ErrorDialog>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

onClick(): void {
this.dialogRef.close();
 }
}

openErrorDialog(errore: string): void{
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorDialog, {
        width: '80%',
        data: { error: errore }
        //panelClass: 'myDialogStyle'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can pass a custom panelClass in your matDialogConfig Object ([doc here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig))

so

```
openErrorDialog(errore: string): void{
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorDialog, {
        width: '80%',
        data: { error: errore }
        panelClass: 'custom-modalbox'
    });
}
```

And in your custom panelClass you can override the padding :

```
.custom-modalbox {
    mat-dialog-container {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

But your .custom-modalbox should be global scoped to be applied (not defined in the component styles )

Comment: The property "panelClass" targets the overlay pane and not the dialog itself. The Angular Material Docs suggest to simply provide CSS rules in the global style.css in order to overwrite default material rules/styles.

Comment: @Francesco yes but if you want a specific css for a dialog you need to have a discrimant in your css. So adding a custom panelClass will helps

Comment: If you use @Component({viewEncapsulation.None}) you can keep the class declaration inside component's CSS file.

Comment: @Please_Dont_Bully_Me_SO_Lords I like your approach, but the syntax is like this: `@Component({encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None})`

Comment: is there a way to set `panelClass` in the HTML no when opening the dialog ?

Comment: Is this possible in an angular library?  There is no global css class.

Answer (score 19):

This will definitely work:

```
::ng-deep.mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach.

Comment: I support your answer ng-Deeply ;)

Comment: if you do changes in mat-dialog-container it will be reflected in all the dialog box. Now suppose you have two dialog box one is for error which should come at the bottom (Like snack-bar). and the other is for success which should cover the whole screen. This method won't work there.

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated and using !important is a very bad practice... This approach may work, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @ArthurSenna ng-deep is deprecated but no standard alternative has been provided by Angular team - there are techniques that help https://dev.to/jwp/angular-10-ng-deep-and-host-pseudo-classes-1kbg

Comment: "This will definitely work" - Not it doesn't.

Comment: @Eric Please crosscheck your styles it always works am still using it.

Comment: This should not be used.  By using ::ng-deep you break encapsulation of those styles across your application and should be used with caution with Material design since it will cause undesired styles to affect other elements sharing class names.

Ways to prevent this: 

- Use :host  as a prefix to your ::ng-deep to keep encapsulation and prevent bleeding of your styles to other elements sharing the same class name. 

- Style in CSS via adding a class when defining the modal: 

 let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorDialog, {
        panelClass: 'my-modal'
    });

Answer (score 17):

You should use panelClass on the component at the same time as ::ng-deep on the css.

```
openErrorDialog(errore: string): void{
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorDialog, {
    width: '80%',
    data: { error: errore }
    panelClass: 'custom-modalbox'
});
}
```

in css:

```
::ng-deep .custom-modalbox {
mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: The best answer in my opinion, because it allows customizing only specific dialog instead of a global approach.

Comment: This is working perfectly, the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just need .custom-modalbox {
  .mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

Comment: This is a better approach because it allows you to specify which dialog to style while using ::ng-deep

Answer (score 10):

I just change this, it works perfectly:

```
.custom-modalbox >  mat-dialog-container {
        padding: 0px;
}
```

Here there is a working example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-dialog?file=src/styles.css

Comment: A more elegant solution IMO.

Comment: Clean solution, might I suggest adding the piece where you add this custom class name when defining the modal in your component.ts file :)

Answer (score 7):

panelClass works perfectly when your styles are global scoped  otherwise it won't as styles are not available.

Add ng-deep before your styles to access it globally!!

```
::ng-deep {

 .custom-dialog > mat-dialog-container {
        padding: 0px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach the solution is to change the code only at a single place. This can be done be using the code:

```
::ng-deep.mat-dialog-container {
overflow: visible;
}
```

This helps you to change the code only at a single place rather than changing at all the places. This works perfectly. No need to declare anything else anywhere apart from the corresponding CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me in angular 13

in  style.css

```
::ng-deep #dialogTrasparent{
  padding: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background: transparent !important;

}
```

and componenet.ts

```
const loader = this.dialog.open(DialogLoader, 
{id: 'dialogTrasparent'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't set all desired styles in the `mat-dialog` config. [MatDialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) allows you to set only width, height, max/min-width, max/min-height, and custom classes in the config to operate by them for some specific options.
But also you can set up global styles for modal in `styles.scss` file.
*.ts

```
let dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(
   SomeEntryComponent, 
   <MatDialogConfig>modalConfig // <- there you can set width/height
);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: any) => { /* do stuff */ });
```

global styles.scss

```
.cdk-overlay-pane mat-dialog-container.mat-dialog-container { // <- in this way all other styles
  margin: 20px 5px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the CSS in the global file and we can use the Mat Dialog API to add the css

**Example**

```
   constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MetricCreateComponent>) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dialogRef.addPanelClass('custom-dialog-container-metric-configure');
    }


    onRemoveClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.removePanelClass('custom-dialog-container-metric-configure');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own custom class and set it up in the dialog property panelClass.

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      data: this.data,
      panelClass: 'my-custom-container'
    });
}
```

In your styles.css/styles.scss you write down your custom rules. Then you said you wanted to style the mat-dialog-title, in order to do that I used the browser inspector and searched for a class name to target (to see the actual class name angular gave it to the html element). I found that name to be 'mat-mdc-dialog-title' and I used it in my rules.

```
.my-custom-container {
    background-color: aqua;
}
/* Increasing css specificity by duplicating class */
/* Increasing the specificity is important to overwrite angular
   own rules on the component, without it your rules do not win 
   against angular material dialog's rules.
*/
.my-custom-container .mat-mdc-dialog-title.mat-mdc-dialog-title {
    color: blue;
}
```

Your dialog's html should look something like this:

```
<section class="my-custom-container">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Delete file</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    Would you like to delete cat.jpeg?
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-button color="accent" mat-dialog-close>No</button>
    <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary" mat-dialog-close>Yes</button>
  </div>
</section>
```