# create a module like angular material dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a component like angular material dialog but dont want to use that. I want to create a component and pass that a component and show it in the modal.

How can I create a component to show other component in the modal and can resize the width and height (in angular dialog can not the size or i can use the ngDeep but i can not use that because it effective other dialogs) ?

Comment: For set width and height you can use config (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig)

Comment: In mat dialog you can use, e.g. 50% to heigth or to width, if you want a resizable modal, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776046/how-to-make-angular-material-dialog-re-sizable-in-angular-7

Comment: Minor corrections

Comment: You can also change styles of specific dialog by adding `panelClass`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48689004/11719787) might be helpful.

Comment: Any solution around this question?

Answer (score 0):

Angular MatDialg based on [overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api). You can use `OverlayModule` for creating you own modals service.

But if you just need to set height and width of modal you can handle it with [MatDialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig)

Comment: it must be the resonsive

Comment: then you can use `panelClass` as mentioned above (in comments).